# Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKTextRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, google-mlkit

I'm developing a flutter app using the google_mlkit_text_recognition 0.10.0 package.

When trying to run on my iPhone or simulator, I receive following error message:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           182.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKTextRecognizer

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKTextRecognizerOptions

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKVisionImage

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

My device is Macbook Pro M1 Pro (2021) and I tried running the app on an iPhone 12 (real device) and iPhone 14 Pro (simulator), respectively.

Do you have any other suggestion how to fix the error?

Thank you in advance!

Best wishes to the community!

I also tried different suggestions such as "flutter clean", "flutter channel master", deleting and updating pod files. None of the suggestions worked. I always receive the error message above.